# I can't manage to get my html coded slideshow to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow

I'm working on making a slideshow for my website. I'm trying to get one working with arrows and stuff. But i wanted to start simple. I think that its something with the jquery but im not sure. The images are there just for testing. I got the slider from reallysimpleworks so this is what i have so far:

**Edited: the  that was suggested in the answers. Added the source of my slider in the text.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.rs-slideshow {
    border: 12px solid #444;
    height: 240px;
    margin: 24px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 620px;
}

.rs-slideshow .slide-container {
    background-color: #444;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.rs-slideshow .slide-container img {
    position: absolute;
}

/*    Hide the slide data container    */
.rs-slideshow .slides {
    display: none;
}
</style>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#slideshow-div').rsfSlideshow();
})

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="slideshow-div" class="rs-slideshow">


    <div class="slide-container">
        <img src="http://integrationalism.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/lol1.jpg"
            alt="The first image in a slideshow demo." title="This is the first slide" />
    </div>

    <ol class="slides">
        <li>
            <a href="<--The same as above but due to the fact that i can only post 2 links i added this text-->"</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<--The same as above but due to the fact that i can only post 2 links i added this text-->"</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<--The same as above but due to the fact that i can only post 2 links i added this text-->"</a>
        </li>
    </ol>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You wrote wrong syntax of script... in script tag remove src and paste you logic in script tag like you use li tag...

Comment: Your `<style>` tag needs to be within the `<head>` tag. Your HTML as-is is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script section is not correct. It have to be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.rs.slideshow.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#slideshow-div').rsfSlideshow();
})

</script>
```

You need to download [`jquery.rs.slideshow.min.js`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andygott/Really-Simple-Slideshow/master/js/jquery.rs.slideshow.min.js) and save it in your project folder.

Comment: Also, he might want to include a minified javascript file of the jQuery plugin he wants to use:
http://reallysimpleworks.com/slideshow/

Comment: First Marten "bedankt" for awnsering so fast. But its still not working the way i want to. its loading the second image now.(skipping the first) and doesn't continue sliding to the next one

Comment: o.O i just started coding :P. I honestly dont know what you mean with a minified javascript file of the plugin or where i can find it.

Comment: I wrote an edit to the orginal answer, which will be visible to you after it is peer reviewed.

Comment: Indeed, that's correct. You can even download the other files here: https://github.com/reallysimple/Really-Simple-Slideshow/zipball/master